# Резиновый квадратный блок

Tags: вёрстка

Доброго времени суток. Уважаемые знатоки прошу вашей помощи.
Хочу сделать резиновый **квадратный** блок, параметр Width задаю в процентах (что бы обеспечить норм отображение на всех мониторах). 
Как сделать так: измеряем длину Width в пикселах или других единицах, после чего присвоить значение параметру height значение взятое в Width.

Или быть может у вас есть свои идеи как это сделать
Вот примерный код, который не могу довести до ума:

```
<div style ="width:20%" id = 'divv'>
<script>
 var x = $(this).width('divv');<br>
 var y = $(this).height('divv');<br>
 if (x > y) y=x <br>
 var b = document.getElementByclassName('divv');<br>
 b.style.width = x;<br>
b.style.height = x;   <br>
 document.body.appendChild(d);<br>
else x=y<br>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var element = $('#div');
 function math_height() {
  element.height(element.width());
 }
 math_height();
 $(window).on('resize',function () {
  math_height();
 });
});
```

Comment: Andrei Goncharov<br>
Скрипт работает!! <br>
Большое спасибо!!<br>
Только вопрос:<br>
зачем   math_height(); два раза в конце<br>
и <br>
растолкуйте пожалуйста это:<br>
$(window).on('resize',function ()<br>
Очень интересно)))<br>

Comment: функция math_height() - высчитывает высоту от ширины.Дальше ее надо применять по какому-то событию. Изначально применяем ее по событию $(document).ready(), и по событию изменения ширины браузера $(window).on('resize'). Можно еще для точности применить ее по событию $(window).on('load') - оно отработает после полной загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагаются относительные значения `width`, как в вашем случае, можно воспользоваться, например, `padding-top`

```css
#divv {
  background: #a11dc2;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'divv'></div>
```